# How to write mybatis mapper for this inserting in temporary table created in between?

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-redshift, mybatis, mybatis-mapper

I'm trying to write mapper using annotation mybatis for the following sql extract :

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE XYZ
.
/* Something */
.


CREATE TEMP TABLE ABC
as
Select ptype,pvalue,id,djob
from XYZ
where  pvalue> 0 
and CASE WHEN djob = ptype
then pvalue = d_job_partition_value END;

Insert into ABC
Select ptype,pvalue,id,djob
from XYZ
where 
CASE WHEN ptype = 'region' AND d_job_partition_type = 'region' 
THEN pvalue in (Select distinct CAST(region_id as NUMERIC(38,0)) from {db}.{table} where region_id=d_job_partition_value) END;
```

The mapper class that I tried to write keeping in mind that `ABC` is a temporary table created in between.

```java
@Select("with XYZ as 
         (
         /* Something */
         ),
         ABC as (
         Select ptype,pvalue,id,djob
         from XYZ
         where  pvalue> 0 
         and CASE WHEN djob = ptype
         then pvalue = d_job_partition_value END),

         insert into ABC
         (ptype,pvalue,id,djob) values(
           Select ptype,pavalue,id,djob
           from XYZ
           CASE WHEN ptype = 'region' AND d_job_partition_type = 'region' 
           THEN pvalue in (Select distinct CAST(region_id as NUMERIC(38,0)) from {db}.{table} 
            where region_id=d_job_partition_value) END ")
```

The error is :

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "into"
    [junit]   Position: 5828
    [junit]     at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:23)
    [junit]     at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:107)
    [junit]     at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:98)
    [junit]     at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionManager$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionManager.java:282)
    [junit]     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.selectList(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionManager.selectList(SqlSessionManager.java:171)
    [junit]     at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:114)
    [junit]     at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:58)
    [junit]     at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:43)
    [junit]     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.okey(Unknown Source)
```

I'm aware that `@Insert` is used to *insert values*. But in this case, creation of temp table is creating problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which SQL are you using? The syntax create temp table abc as looks like Oracle and not like the SQL-Server which would be select ... into ##tablename

Comment: It's only sql  not oracle. The sql is working fine. the only problem is because of using in mapper class.

Comment: On the Microsoft sql server I'm getting: Unknown object type 'TEMP' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.

Comment: @casenonsensitive You can use any example to create temp table, that's not the point. The main issue here is  convert the creation of temp table and insert in the mapper class.

Comment: Ok, are you getting any messages / warnings / errors? What are they?

Comment: What's the specific database? The answer is very database-specific.

Comment: It's redshift database and SQL engine is PostgreSQL. @TheImpaler

Comment: Maybe it's with the insert statement: can you remove the part `values(` ? I'm asking because you're providing a query and not a tuple of values.

Comment: Are you sure that SQL statement is legal in redshift? Have you tried running it manually?

Comment: @casenonsensitive yes i tried that before but was throwing same error. Then I switched to this way because it's the way we insert in table using annotation Insert.

Comment: @TheImpaler I ran that query in dBeaver and that is also working fine.

Comment: Maybe it's because ABC is a CTE and also the target of the insert ? Or maybe just the trailing comma after the CTE ?

Comment: @casenonsensitive I also tried with removing trailing comma but same issue occured. The main question here is can we insert a query using  annotation Select?

Comment: You should be able with `@Insert` - why would you need `@Select` ?

Comment: because I'm creating a temporary table in between in which I've to insert data. And in @Insert we can insert in real table only. If possible, can you show how would you do that as in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple statements (including temp table creation) in `@Insert` annotation on mapper method:

```
@Insert(
  "create temp table xyz as select * from whatever; " +
  "CREATE TEMP TABLE ABC as Select ptype,pvalue,id,djob from XYZ;" +
  "Insert into ABC Select ptype,pvalue,id,djob from XYZ;"
)
void insertMultiple();
```

This solution works not only in postgres. I've check and it works with H2 as well.

Note that the option you are trying namely [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) a.k.a `with`-query does not create a temporary table.

They look like temporary table and even documentation says they `can be thought of as defining temporary tables that exist just for one query` but this is only for explanatory purposes. They are not temporary tables and the important difference is that it is not possible to do insert into this auxiliary statements.